# Rename a stopped container

Tags: docker

I ran a container sometime back and now it's killed. Now I want to start another container with the same name but don't want to remove the existing container. Is there any way I can rename the stopped container?

I had this container running with the name `test-exit`

```
129345a41ce3   python3.10   "start_command.sh"   About an hour ago   Exited (255) 4 minutes ago test-exit
```

Now that it's stopped. I want to preserve it with the name `test-exit-trail-1` and start another container with the name `test-exit`. Is there any way I can do that?

It should be trivial I guess. I might be missing some right keywords to search on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation [man docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_rename/)

```
docker container rename old-name new-name
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
docker rename old-name new-name
```

Example

```
docker rename test-exit new_name
```

Do some check:

```
docker container ls -a
```